# Why DefaultConnection in MVC 5 has 2 connection strings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, connection-string

Just curious. Why when a new MVC5 project is created, there are 2 connection strings.

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Application1.Web
-20140107075640.mdf;

Initial Catalog=aspnet-Application1.Web-20140107075640;Integrated Security=True"
```

Any reason for that? Also, what's that number `20140107075640` about?

Comment: I only see one connection string in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see one connection string when I create a project:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication7-20140107051904.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication7-20140107051904;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The random number (or timestamp, I think) is to ensure that the database is uniquely named.  If you've created a project Foo in the past and it created a new database in SQL Server LocalDB, then if you create a second project called Foo, you'll end up sharing the database.  Usually, this isn't desirable, so a randomizing token is inserted into the connection string to keep them unique.  You can always customize the Initial Catalog value to whatever you'd prefer.

Comment: I see. So why use `AttachDbFilename` and `Initial Catalog` ?

Comment: @Richard77 AttachDbFilename is to place the DB into the project folder (under App_Data) rather than the SQL default data directory.  InitialCatalog is to give it a friendly name (well, as friendly as you can get with a random number).  Either one of these could be removed and remain functional, but why not keep both?

Comment: make too much sense. Thank you so much.